# Why is 'text' not appearing as an option for background-clip in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a heading which has a gradient colour. I've found how to do this online by using '''background-clip: text;'''

However when I try to do this my VS Code does not show a "text" option for background-clip. See below:
[VS Code options for background-clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z0gw.png)

Why is this not an option for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-clip/) helps with explaining it more. Scroll down to the `text` heading where you can read more about it. It does work, just not how it used to.

```
.background-clip-text {
  
  /* if we can clip, do it */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;

  /* what will show through the text
      ~ or ~
     what will be the background of that element */
  background: whatever;

  /* fallback text color
      ~ or ~
     the actual color of text, so it better work on the background */
  color: red;
 
}
```

In order for this to work properly, you will need to apply `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` to the element you want this style on.